# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am aware that this has been asked so many times, but my problem doesn't seem to go away. I've already put the delimiter in the correct places but i still keep on getting error 'Error(9,1): Encountered the symbol "/" ' at line 9. If I'm not mistaken, the delimiter that causes the error shold be there.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE FOR_CLASS_NOV2 AS

PROCEDURE PRINT_SNAME(S_NO S.SNO%TYPE);

FUNCTION FIND_MAX_QTY
RETURN NUMBER;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY FOR_CLASS_NOV2 AS

PROCEDURE PRINT_SNAME(S_NO S.SNO%TYPE) IS
S_SNAME S.SNAME%TYPE;

BEGIN
  SELECT SNAME
  INTO S_SNAME
  FROM S
  WHERE SNO = S_NO;

  DBMS_OUT.PUT_LINE('SUPPLIER NAME IS: ' || S_NAME);
END PRINT_SNAME;

FUNCTION FIND_MAX_QTY()
RETURN NUMBER IS

M_QTY NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT AX(STY)
  INTO M_QTY
  FROM SP;
  RETURN M_QTY;
END FIND_MAX_QTY;

END;
/
```

Comment: How are you running the script? You tagged 2 different client tools, so that's a but confusing.

Comment: `/` is typically used when running the script against SQLPlus client.  It should not be there when running it with SQLDeveloper

Comment: It shouldn't be used PL/SQL Developer either, except in a Command or SQL Window (which you typically wouldn't use for PL/SQL).

Comment: Your code works for me in PL/SQL Developer version 9.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use parenthesis in the function when there's no parameters.

Try replacing this:

```
FUNCTION FIND_MAX_QTY()
RETURN NUMBER IS
```

With this:

```
FUNCTION FIND_MAX_QTY
RETURN NUMBER IS
```

Also, you have a variable named `S_SNAME` but you're printing `S_NAME`.